# Simulate Background Fetch with Instruments

Tags: ios, ios7, instruments

Is there a way to Simulate Background Fetch when debugging app with Instruments?

**EDIT**
In regard to Ducanan comment, by Simulate Background Fetch I mean new iOS7 feature, my client claims that app get much slower after few hours in background, it doesn't happen on iOS6 so I assume that there is some problem with my background fetch implementation, but I don't know how to debug it with Instruments

Comment: Your question is wayyyyyy too vague to be meaningful. You're going to have to provide more information. What do yo mean background fetch, specifically?

Answer (score 3):

Run time profiler then select tab Instrument and in context menu choose Simulate Background fetch. Run profiler on device, not on simulator

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail: "select tab Instrument and in context menu" is quite vague.

Comment: I added screenshot to answer